# suggestion result with offline mao

Tags: android, here-api

I have downloaded offline map and with MapEngine.setOnline(false) to make it working offline with that area, the map can be shown, but when I try to search some location, the suggestions list are very less than with online map, is that supposed to be so or anything wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want complete offline operation, yes the search results will be limited when operating in offline mode (i.e. `MapEngine#setOnline(false)`). The offline search database is limited compared to online.

If you don't require being fully offline (i.e. no data being used whatsoever) keep in mind that simply by preloading the map data as you have done, far less data will be used by the HERE SDK during normal operation, so you can not call `MapEngine#setOnline(false)` and still allow Routing, Search, etc. to go online to get better results.

If you want to keep the SDK offline but only allow Search to go online, you can override the global (`MapEngine`) setting when making search requests by calling `setConnectivity(Connectivity#ONLINE)` for your search `Request` objects.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! But that means in the case of no network connection, even if I call setConnectivity(Connectivity#ONLINE), the search results will be the same as still can  not get info online, right ?

Comment: @WillWang Actually if you call `setConnectivity(Connectivity#ONLINE)` and have no network connection the request would fail, so you would then have to fall back to an offline request at which point the results would be from the offline database.